# Vectorized string interpolation in Pandas? Is this doable without iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, string-formatting

### The set up

I want to add a new column that contains a URL that has a base/template form and should have certain values interpolated into it based on the information contained in the row.

### Table

[image: The table data]

### What I would LOVE to be able to do

```py
base_link = "https://www.vectorbase.org/Glossina_fuscipes/Location/View?r=%(scaffold)s:%(start)s-%(end)s"

# simplify getting column data from data_frame
start = operator.attrgetter('start')
end = operator.attrgetter('end')
scaffold = operator.attrgetter('seqname')

def get_links_to_genome_browser(data_frame):
    base_links = pd.Series([base_link]*len(data_frame.index))
    links = base_links % {"scaffold":scaffold(data_frame),"start":start(data_frame),"end":end(data_frame)}
    return links
```

Answer (score 2):

So I am answering my own question but I finally figured it out so I want to close this out and record the solution.

The solution is to use `data_frame.apply()` but to change my indexing syntax in the `get_links_to_genome_browser` function to `Series` syntax rather than `DataFrame` indexing syntax.

```
def get_links_to_genome_browser(series):
    link = base_link % {"scaffold":series.ix['seqname'],"start":series.ix['start'],"end":series.ix['end']}
    return link
```

Then call it like:

```
df.apply(get_links_to_genome_browser, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're asking.  Let me know

```
base_link = "https://www.vectorbase.org/Glossina_fuscipes/Location/View?r=%(scaffold)s:%(start)s-%(end)s"
```

then you can do something like this

```
data_frame['url'] = base_link + data_frame['start'] + data_frame['end'] + etc...
```